# How to decode UTF8 characters with JSON on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json

I'm using ASIHTTP Request to get a NSString response that I give to a SBJSON parser.

The problem is that inside the NSString response I got some UTF8 encoded character(accent) that I need do decode to make the app works.

How can I decode UTF8 with JSON ?

I call the JSON message like this:

```
[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];
```

Any help would be so appreciated.

Fabrizio

Answer (score 4):

lol....
great !
but for more simplicity i will say.

Create new SBJSON parser object

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
```

Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];
```

Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
    returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Parse the JSON response into an object
Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects

```
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]
```

And in statuses array you have all the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized I didn't have to decode, the response is correctly read.

Thanx for reading.

Fabrizio